# Pop up disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this React Native code, where I need to enter input in a pop up. But, every time I click on the button to view the pop-up, it appears for the first time and then disappears immediately if I try to enter any value.

```
const [sendAddress, setSendAddress] = React.useState(false);
const [a, setA] = React.useState('');

<View style={styles.card}>
  <View style={styles.cardInfo}>
    <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>Set Value</Text>
      <View style={styles.parent}>
        <DialogInput isDialogVisible={sendAddress}
          title={"Send Address"}
          message={"Enter address"}
          hintInput ={"Insert Address"}
          submitInput={ (inputText) => { setA(inputText); } }
          closeDialog={ () => { setSendAddress(false);}}
        >
        </DialogInput>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setSendAddress(true)}>
            <LinearGradient colors={['#FFA07A', '#FF6347']}style={styles.button}>    
              <Text style={[styles.text, {color: 'black'}]}>Enter Address</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
          </TouchableOpacity>               
      </View>                
  </View>
</View>
```

After the Submit button is clicked once, it no more displays the modal when clicked again.
I cannot find any error in the code. Any suggestion or correction will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example? Like a Snack? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jnpdx I have updated it with a minimal code.

Comment: This seems to be working as expected? https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/thoughtful-pretzels

Comment: But it doesn't work on my emulator and mobile. I couldn't figure out any error in the code either.